# Como funciona o algoritmo de ranqueamento Ranker combinado ao Information Gain do Weka

Tags: inteligência-artificial, weka

Como disse no título, gostaria de saber como eles funcionam juntos e quais os passos que eles seguem se possível. Ambos são utilizados em conjunto no Weka para gerar um ranqueamento de atributos numa base de dados qualquer.